# Instantiate spawn just one time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a dust effect, it's working but works just once, here is my code:

```
if ((Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded == false))){
            if (ativar < maxAtivar){
                Particula ();
                Destroy (GameObject.Find ("Poeira(Clone)"), delay);
            } 
        }
```

Particula function:

```
void Particula(){
    Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, 0), player.transform.rotation);
    ativar++;
}
```

I don't know how to make this repeat, suggestions please :D

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to place your code in an `Update` or `FixedUpdate` method, like this:

```
void Update()
{
    ...
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    ...
}
```

It's important to know the difference between the two though. `FixedUpdate` runs once each frame, in step with the physics engine, while `Update` doesn't.

Comment: doesnt Update runs once each frame and FixedUpdate once each Physics-step which can be multiple per frame?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Destroy (GameObject.Find ("Poeira(Clone)"), delay); **this destroys every dust object in your scene so;**
if ((Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded == false))){
            if (ativar < maxAtivar){
                Particula ();
               //close this Destroy (GameObject.Find ("Poeira(Clone)"), delay); 
            } 
        } 
    void Particula(){
       GameObject obj =(GameObject) Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, 0), 
      player.transform.rotation);
       Destroy (obj, delay); //destroy here 
        ativar++;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and this is happening: https://gyazo.com/3b756d0662cb31f95ab596f4220ee598

Comment: it is because when you push up arrow it goes through if statement many times. You can control this adding a boolean maybe. You can make it instantiate smoke once only you push uparrow. You have many choices according to your game design.

Comment: I figured out!! The only thing that I need to change was GetKeyDown, thanks!!